# In SceneKit with swift trying to move character with a touch

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I cannot find an answer to this that is recent and not in objective c.  Im using SceneKit with swift and Im trying to move my character node to the spot where the user clicks.  Ive tried using hit result in touches began but my floor node is located at (0, 0, 0) so it is useless when it hits that which would be most of the time a user clicks on screen.  I was about to get out my old calculus book, but then I realized I have no idea how to convert when the touch location is always relative to the screen position which is moving around the scene. If anyone could show me a link or give some advice I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert between view and scene coordinates you can use the projectPoint and unprojectPoint methods of the scene renderer, see documentation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer

They will let you convert points either way between the 3D coordinate system of your scene and the 2D coordinate system of the view it is displayed in.

***update***

What you want to do is call the unproject function twice, once with the z set to zero (with the x/y view coordinates) and once with it set to one. That will give you 2 points in the 3d world, imagine a line between them and you need to work out where that line intersects your floor plane. That will be the point you need.

Comment: Thanks I see the documentation now.  I am still confused though, why is the argument a SCNVector3? Im trying to go from a CGPoint that is all I'm getting from touches began to a SCNVector3.

Comment: fun unprojectPoint(SCNVector3)

Comment: It is because a point on the screen goes to a line in the 3d world, you set a value between 0 and 1 to specify where along the line in the 3d world the point should be (between near and far clipping planes). See the documentation for details and you can ask a more specific question on stack overflow if you need help with the code. If my answer has helped please mark it as accepted, thanks :)

Comment: Ok you've helped a ton, I almost have it working but I'm doing something wrong with the clipping plane part.  The character moves way farther than the click I want the point where it intersects my floor plane to be the point on the vector where I get coordinates from.

Comment: let touch = touches.first!                                                                               
        let location = touch.location(in: scnView)
        let hit = scnView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3Make(Float(location.x), Float(location.y) , 0))
        let moveToVector = SCNVector3Make(hit.x, 0, hit.z)

Comment: What you want to do is call the unproject function twice, once with the z set to zero (with the x/y view coordinates) and once with it set to one. That will give you 2 points in the 3d world, imagine a line between them and you need to work out where that line intersects your floor plane. That will be the point you need.

Comment: Ok, cool. It will always be a different place though depending on where you click since I'm at an angle.  Would be easy if the plane were always in the middle of the two points but it won't be.  I need to figure out where the point is with the hit test but it just registers floor as (0, 0, 0).  I'll try and look more at how to use the hit test I guess.

Comment: You can do it with some simple 3d maths for where a line intersects a plane.

Comment: Just figured it out! You were right, I just read the documentation again and found that hit results can return a local SCNVector3 coordinate and the character moves right to the click now where it intersects my floor plane.  Now I just have to figure out how to make his velocity constant lol.  I did it in sprite kit a long time ago so shouldn't be that different.